# What to do when the best answer doesn't solve the question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answers

I have a peculiar situation.

I asked this [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/290213/unknown-design-pattern?noredirect=1#comment600853_290213) and someone answered the question well by saying that the implementation I was planning on using is more of an anti-pattern as it is not addressing the problem and suggested using single-responsibility (which technically is the way it is currently implemented) so I marked this as correct.

My problem here though is that another person answered suggesting that instead of using what I am, use a builder pattern with chained methods. I said I didn't like that idea because there wasn't any way to specify mandatory fields but then someone else commented on that answer with a solution which uses the builder pattern and allows for mandatory fields which are obvious to a developer using the object.

I personally think that the commented solution is a much better solution to the problem that I described, but the question was, what is this pattern.

So who should get the points? The original accepted answer. The person who suggested the builder pattern because in the comments to that answer is the solution. Or whether I should ask the person who commented to write that as an answer?

Please help me as I want to make sure anyone else who comes across this post has the best advice.

Comment: see [Is it acceptable to improve other people' answers to your own question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255057/839601) at MSO

Comment: Thanks that is really useful. So basically it sounds like I should create my own answer which is a combination of both answers on the post and the comment. I wasn't sure whether this would be frowned upon in the community but by the looks of that post you shared it seems like the better option.

Comment: just make sure that your answer 1) looks good (otherwise people will vote it down) 2) [can stand on its own](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/165773) (not as "see <this link> and <this link>") and 3) has proper attribution to answers and comments it builds upon

Comment: you really got to click and read the link in prior comment, at words "can stand on its own"